# Problem with even indexes in Java program

Tags: java

The method takes 2 parameters (String,char) and returns the string with the char replaced by `'+'` if index is even and `'#'` if index is odd.

The String I use is `"Mary Bella Abracadabra"` and the expected output is `"M+ry Bell+ +br#c#d#br+"`. Instead I get `"M#ry Bell# #br#c#d#br#"`.

I can't find the error in my code. It seems that all indexes where char ch is found are odd.

```
public String emphasize (String phrase, char ch){
    String phraseEmph = "";
    char c1 = '#';
    char c2 = '+';
    for (int i=0; i < phrase.length(); i++){
         char c = phrase.charAt(i);
         char cc = Character.toLowerCase(c);
         if ((cc == ch) && ((i % 2) == 0)){
            phraseEmph = phrase.replace(c,c2);
            phrase = phraseEmph;   
            }
         else if ((cc == ch) && ((i % 2)!= 0)){
            phraseEmph = phrase.replace(c,c1);
            phrase = phraseEmph;   
            }  
         phrase = phrase; 
    }
    return phrase;
}

public void testEmphasize(){
    String phrase = "Mary Bella Abracadabra";
    char ch = 'a';
    String Emphasized = emphasize(phrase,ch);
    System.out.println("Emphasized : " + Emphasized);
}
```

Comment: You probably should get rid of the phrase = phrase, since it does nothing and is potentially confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note Array start with 0 in java. String is immutable and don't provide many mutable methods. It's best to make use of StringBuilder as shown below both for easiness and memory efficiency.

```
    public static String emphasize(String phrase, char ch) {
    StringBuilder phraseEmph = new StringBuilder(phrase);
    char c1 = '#';
    char c2 = '+';
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {

        char c = phrase.charAt(i);
        char cc = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        if ((cc == ch) && ((i % 2) == 0)) {
            phraseEmph.setCharAt(i, c2);
        } else if ((cc == ch) && ((i % 2) != 0)) {
            phraseEmph.setCharAt(i, c1);
        }
    }
    return phraseEmph.toString();
}
```

Comment: The check : cc == ch  is performed twice which is not needed and also  (i % 2) should be checked only once and not again in else.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `replace` it doesn't just replace the current `'a'`, it replaces *all* of them. You'll need to find a different way to replace characters so that you only change one at a time.

<sup>(I've purposefully avoided suggesting a fix. It'll be more educational if you come up with it yourself.)</sup>

Comment: But it does't find any even indexes at all, even if i remove the else if statement.

Comment: What's the difference between `i` and `idx`? Do you even need `idx`?

Comment: This answer points at the coding error, which IMO is better than providing a different solution which works. When you hit the first 'a', all of them in the string are replaced with the character suitable for the index of this first 'a'. After that, no more 'a's are found, because they've all been replaced. Incidentally, the uppercase 'A' will not be replaced when the first 'a' is found, but it's on an odd index as well so it gets the same replacement character.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions.

- use a `StringBuilder` to make the character replacements. Intialize to the original string.  You can then use `setCharAt` to make the change.
- Use indexOf in conjunction with `toLowerCase`.  Then you don't need to verify if you found the character, just use the index returned and return the final string if -1.
- then just check for even or or indices like you are doing but assign to a holding char variable.
- Then use that to replace the character.  Like this pseudocode

```
    char repl;
    if (even) {
       repl = '#';
    } else {
       repl = '+';
    }
    make replacement
```

- don't do a check for both even or odd.  Just check for one condition, Otherwise it must be the other condition (not need to check again).

Aside from my recommendations, here is another way of doing it.

The main difference is that it uses the even/odd result to index into the array to replace the character.

```
public static String emphasize(String phrase, char ch) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(phrase);
    char[] chars = { '#', '+' };
    int idx = -1;
    while ((idx = phrase.toLowerCase().indexOf(ch, idx + 1)) >= 0) {
        sb.setCharAt(idx, chars[idx % 2]);
        phrase = sb.toString();
    }
    return phrase;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` for concatenation to a string inside a loop because it is much faster and consumes less memory.
2. Convert both the characters in the same case (e.g. lowercase) before comparing. This way, you can pass the character to the function in any case.
3. You should not use `String#replace` for this case as it replaces all occurrences of replacement character/string in the string being replaced.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(emphasize("Mary Bella Abracadabra", 'a'));
        System.out.println(emphasize("Mary Bella Abracadabra", 'A'));
    }

    public static String emphasize(String phrase, char ch) {
        char c1 = '#';
        char c2 = '+';
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Convert the char parameter to lower case
        char chLower = Character.toLowerCase(ch);

        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            char c = phrase.charAt(i);
            if (Character.toLowerCase(c) == chLower) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    sb.append(c1);
                } else {
                    sb.append(c2);
                }
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
M+ry Bell+ +br#c#d#br+
M+ry Bell+ +br#c#d#br+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very inefficient, my suggestion :

```
class emphasize {
    private String phrase;
    private char ch;
    public emphasize(String phrase, char ch) {
        this.phrase = phrase;
        this.ch = ch;
    }
    public String execute() {
        char chars[] = phrase.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < chars.length ; i++) {
            /* As char is primitive type I can use == */
            if (chars[i]==Character.toLowerCase(ch) || chars[i]==Character.toUpperCase(ch)) chars[i] = i%2==0 ? '+' : '#';
        }
        return String.valueOf(chars);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrase = "Mary Bella Abracadabra";
        char ch = 'a';
        emphasize obj = new emphasize(phrase, ch);
        System.out.println(obj.execute());
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter.  I removed my downvote and my comment.  But I recommend instead of the for loop at the end, just do a `String.valueOf(chars);` to create the string.

Answer (score 0):

Full tested simplified code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrase = "Maryaa Bella Abracadabra";
        char ch = 'a';
        System.out.println("Original   : " + phrase);
        String Emphasized = emphasize(phrase,ch);
        System.out.println("Emphasized : " + Emphasized);
    }
    
    public static String emphasize (String phrase, char ch){
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(phrase); 
        char c1 = '#';
        char c2 = '+';
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++){
             char c  = phrase.charAt(i);
             char cc = Character.toLowerCase(c);
             if(cc == ch) {
                 if(i%2 == 0){
                     temp.setCharAt(i, c1);
                 } else {
                     temp.setCharAt(i, c2);
                 }
             }
        }
        return temp.toString();
    }
        
}
```

Output :

```
Original   : Maryaa Bella Abracadabra                                                                                                                          
Emphasized : M+ry#+ Bell+ +br#c#d#br+
```